# what's the performance of Files.readLines in Guava

Tags: java, guava

I read Guava doc:

```
ImmutableList<String> matchingLines = Files.readLines(
  targetFile,
  Charsets.UTF_8,
  new LineProcessor<ImmutableList<String>>() {
    final ImmutableList.Builder<String> builder = ImmutableList.builder();
    @Override public boolean processLine(String line) {
      if(pattern.matches(line)) builder.add(line);
      return true;
    }
    @Override public ImmutableList<String> getResult() {
      return builder.build();
    }
  });
```

so I download the source code ,find the Files.readLines not use **MappedFile technology** ,

so it is less performance of using MappedFile technology.I want to read 50M file ,so how to **improve the performance**

Comment: You can't view a file as
 a string using memory mapped files; there's no way to perform random access on a per-line (or even per-character) basis, even with memory-mapped per-byte random access.  In short, there's no way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Louis why not use memory-mapped read file as Byte,and then parse the the byte to   line .because  can parse  line.separator .

Comment: If you're doing that, you're reading the file sequentially as a stream -- in which case Guava is already doing the right thing.

Comment: @Louis read the file sequentially as a stream is ok! how to use guava read file sequentially by mapped file technology.

Comment: It is not universally the case that "mapped file technology" is just faster.  The Javadoc of `FileChannel.map` states that "From the standpoint of performance it is generally only worth mapping relatively large files into memory."  Guava does not currently have a way to customize how the I/O operations are implemented.

Comment: @Louis Thnaks. Guava has plant to implemented it in future time ?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use a memory-mapped file? Simply needing to read a 50MB file is no reason to use memory-mapping.